# Configure require with amazon s3 bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, requirejs, bucket

I need to configure in some project require.js with amazon s3, I have the url to amazon in the baseUrl. All the scripts are served with amazon S3 but main.js that start the app, is served with my domain, localhost.

How can I configure this, I have modified the require.js file to force baseUrl with the amazon url, but I dont like this way, because if i want to run with static files in local, I cant.

My base url is an amazon url and I have included in the require.config the path 'main' that link to amazon s3 bucket too.

Any idea why only main.js is not served with amazon s3?

Thanks

Comment: please add the code you have so far.